# EC2 with two interfaces (one public and one private)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I basically want a EC2 with one interface in public subnet, one in private. I should be able to SSH through the public interface from outside world, private network will be used to communicate to database in private network.

In terraform...

- I created a VPC, two subnets (one pubilc, one private) in that VPC.
- Created a Internet Gateway, a route table in the vpc with route 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW
- Created a route association between with public subnet and routing table.
- Created a EC2 instance with one interface in public subnet and one in private subnet.
- Created a Elastic IP address on public interface of EC2
- Created a Security group allowing ssh port (22)

Im unable to SSH, connection timeout, could anyone take a look at this?

```
conf_vpc_cidr_block = "10.100.0.0/16"
conf_vpc_enable_dns_support = "true"
conf_vpc_enable_dns_hostnames =  "true"
conf_vpc_enable_classiclink =  "false"
conf_vpc_instance_tenancy = "default"

conf_private_subnet_cidr_block = "10.100.100.0/24"
conf_private_subnet_map_public_ip_on_launch = "false"
conf_private_subnet_availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"

conf_public_subnet_cidr_block = "10.100.200.0/24"
conf_public_subnet_map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
conf_public_subnet_availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"

conf_instance_ami = "ami-000e50175c5f86214"
conf_instance_type = "t3.micro"

provider "aws" {
  region = var.conf_aws_region
  profile = var.conf_aws_profile
}

resource "aws_vpc" "Terraform_XX_VPC" {
  cidr_block = var.conf_vpc_cidr_block
  enable_dns_support = var.conf_vpc_enable_dns_support
  enable_dns_hostnames =  var.conf_vpc_enable_dns_hostnames
  enable_classiclink =  var.conf_vpc_enable_classiclink
  instance_tenancy = var.conf_vpc_instance_tenancy

}

resource "aws_subnet" "Terraform_XX_Private_SN" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.Terraform_XX_VPC.id}"
  cidr_block = var.conf_private_subnet_cidr_block
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.conf_private_subnet_map_public_ip_on_launch
  availability_zone = var.conf_private_subnet_availability_zone

}


resource "aws_subnet" "Terraform_XX_Public_SN" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.Terraform_XX_VPC.id}"
  cidr_block = var.conf_public_subnet_cidr_block
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.conf_public_subnet_map_public_ip_on_launch
  availability_zone = var.conf_public_subnet_availability_zone

}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "Terraform_XX_IGW" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.Terraform_XX_VPC.id}"

}


resource "aws_route_table" "Terraform_XX_Route_Public" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.Terraform_XX_VPC.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block =  "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.Terraform_XX_IGW.id}"
  }

}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "Terraform_XX_Route_Table_Public_Association" {

  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.Terraform_XX_Public_SN.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.Terraform_XX_Route_Public.id}"
}


resource "aws_security_group" "Terraform_XX_SG_ALLOW_SSH" {
  name        = "Terraform_XX_SG_ALLOW_SSH"
  description = "Allow SSH"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.Terraform_XX_VPC.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "Terraform_XX_EC2" {
  ami = var.conf_instance_ami
  instance_type = var.conf_instance_type
  key_name = "${local.environmentLC}"

  network_interface  {
    device_index         = 0
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.Terraform_XX_EC2_Private_Intf.id}"
    #delete_on_termination = true
  }
  network_interface  {
    device_index         = 1
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.Terraform_XX_EC2_Public_Intf.id}"
    #delete_on_termination = true
  }

}

resource "aws_network_interface" "Terraform_XX_EC2_Private_Intf" {
  subnet_id       = "${aws_subnet.Terraform_XX_Private_SN.id}"
  private_ips     = ["10.100.100.5"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.Terraform_XX_SG_ALLOW_SSH.id]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "Terraform_XX_EC2_Public_Intf" {
  subnet_id       = "${aws_subnet.Terraform_XX_Public_SN.id}"
  private_ips     = ["10.100.200.5"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.Terraform_XX_SG_ALLOW_SSH.id]
}

resource "aws_eip" "Terraform_XX_EC2_EIP" {
  vpc             = true
  network_interface = "${aws_network_interface.Terraform_XX_EC2_Public_Intf.id}"
}
```

Comment: can you please confirm that your using the IP address to ssh is public interface public IP address

Comment: @JijoAlexander I have created Elastic ip address, which Im assigning to public interface of the EC2, and Im using that elastic ip address to ssh into from outside aws.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by exchanging the device_index for public and private interface